# Absolute value of cubic polynomial roots lower than 1

Tags: polynomials, roots, absolute-value, cubics

Assume we have a cubic polynomial 
$ x^3 +bx^2+xc+d=0 $, with $b,c,d$ real numbers.

Let $x_1, x_2, x_3 $ be the roots, either real or complex.

What is the relation of the coefficients $b,c$ and $d$ in order to have the roots inside the unit sphere, that means

$ |x_i| < 1$  for  $i=1,2,3$ ?

Comment: For future reference, [cubit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubit)$\neq$ cubic. (Edits made to switch cubit to cubic.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to determine is whether the conditions on $b,c,d$ that make $x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ a [Schur polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_polynomial). As mentioned before, a sufficient (but perhaps unnecessary) condition is that
$$
1>b>c>d
$$
Is true.  For the precise conditions, one may apply either the [Jury test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jury_stability_criterion) or [Bistritz test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bistritz_stability_criterion)

Or, apply the Routh-Hurwitz criterion to 
$$
(z-1)^3p\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right) = \\(1+b+c+d)z^3+ 
(3+b-c-3d)z^2 + (3 - b - c - 3d)z + (1 - b + c - d)
$$
That last option leads to the following statement:

Let $a_3 = 1+b+c+d$, $a_2 = 3+b-c-3d$, $a_1 = 3 - b - c - 3d$, and $a_0 = 1 - b + c - d$. We may state that $x^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ has its roots in the unit ball if and only if all of the following conditions are satisfied:

- $a_i>0$ for each $i$
- $a_2 a_1> a_3 a_0$

Comment: Why do i have to apply the Routh-Hurwitz criterion to the transformed form and not to the original one?

Comment: this criterion is for real roots only?

Comment: This criterion is for complex roots as well. The reason for the transformation is that the Routh-Hurwitz criterion tests whether a polynomial has roots only in the open left half-plane, as opposed to the ball about the origin.

Comment: Can you explain me why you used this tranformation?
Is there any criterion about that?

Comment: The idea behind this transformation is that a polynomial $p$ of degree $d$ will have all its zeros inside the unit circle if and only if the transformed polynomial $(z-1)^dp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$ has its zeros in the (open) left half of the complex plane, i.e. all zeros of the transformed polynomial have a negative real component.

Comment: How can I prove that or is there a proof somewhere online?
(Sorry for many questions, i think this is the last one)

Comment: What you're really looking at are the zeros of $p(f(z))$, where $f(z) = (z+1)/(z-1)$.  Check that if (and only if) $z$ is in the left half of the complex plane, $|f(z)|<1$.  It follows that $p$ is Schur stable if and only if $p(f(z))$, and thus $(z-1)^dp(f(z))$, has all its zeros in the left half of the complex plane.  This $f$ is part of a class of functions known as the Mobius transformations, which are useful for tricks like this one, where one kind of region is mapped to a more manageable one.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the following thorem.

**Theorem** : If $$P(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{n} {a_j}^{z_j}$$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that $$a_n \ge a_{n−1} \ge \cdots \ge {a_1} \ge {a_0} \gt 0,$$
then $P(z)$ has all its zeros in $|z| \le 1$.

This is well known as Enestr¨om–Kakeya theorem. See [here](http://www.ias.ac.in/mathsci/vol117/aug2007/PM2842.PDF) (PDF).

Answer (score 2):

The following is Theorem 1.4 in the book **Periodicities in Nonlinear Difference Equations**, by Grove and Ladas.

Consider the third-degree polynomial equation $$ \lambda^3 + a_2\lambda^2+a_1\lambda + a_0 = 0$$

where $a_0$, $a_1$, $a_2$ are real numbers. Then a necessary and sufficeint condition that all roots lie in the open disk $|\lambda| < 1$ is

$$ | a_2 + a_0|<1+a_1, \quad |a_2 - 3a_0|< 3 - a_1,\quad \text{and} \quad a_0^2+a_1+a_0a_2 < 1. $$

Answer (score 1):

A sufficient condition is 1 > b > c > d > 0 , but I do not know, if there is a condition both sufficient and necessary. Look at kakeya-eneström-theorem.

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial $P$ has all roots inside the open unit disk if an only if $P(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ has all roots in the halfplane ${\frak Re} z < 0$. So for $P(x)$ of degree $n$ consider the polynomial of degree $n$
$$Q(x) = (1-x)^n P(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$$

Now, consider the [Routh-Hurwitz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion#Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_criterion_for_second,_third_and_fourth-order_polynomials) for a cubic polynomial to have all roots in the left half-plane. If $Q(x) = a_3 x^3 + a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0$, the  conditions are  $a_k > 0$ for all $0 \le k\le 3$ and $a_1 a_2 > a_0 a_3$ ( if the leading coefficient is positive).

For $P(x) = x^3 + b x^2 + c x + c$, we get
$$Q(x) = ( 1 - b + c - d)x^3 + (3 - b - c + 3 d)x^2 + ( 3 + b - c - 3 d)x + (1 + b + c + d) $$

Note that we need in any case $1+b+c+d= P(1) > 0$. It follows that all of the coefficients of $Q(x)$ are $> 0$ ( $Q$ apriori could have all coefficients negative, now we see that does not happen).  One more condition is
$$(3 - b - c + 3 d)(3 + b - c - 3 d)> ( 1 - b + c - d) (1 + b + c + d)$$
equivalently

$$1+b d-d^2> c$$

It turns out that two of the above conditions (  $3 -c \pm (b-3 d)>0 $) are superfluous and we get
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid red]{1+b d - d^2 > c > |b+d|-1} $$

a star-shaped ( but not convex) bounded region. Note that the domain in $(b,d)$ space
$$1+b d - d^2 \ge |b+d|-1$$ is a parallelogram with vertices $(-3,-1)$, $(1,-1)$, $(3,1)$, $(-1,1)$.